# Extracting key names with true values from JSONB object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to select keys from `JSONB` type with `true` values. So far I managed to do that using this query but I feel like there is a better way:

```
SELECT json.key
    FROM jsonb_each_text('{"aaa": true, "bbb": false}'::JSONB) json 
    WHERE json.value = 'true';
```

What I don't like is the `WHERE` clause where I'm comparing `strings`. Is there a way to cast it to `boolean`?
If yes, would it work for `truthy` and `falsy` values too? (explanation of `truthy` and `falsy` values in javascript: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/713894/Truthy-Vs-Falsy-Values-in-JavaScript).

Comment: `jsonb` has an equality operator (`=`; unlike `json`), so you could write `FROM jsonb_each(...) json WHERE json.value = jsonb 'true'` (with `jsonb_each_text()` you rely on some JSON values' text representation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonb` has an equality operator (`=`; unlike `json`), so you could write

```
SELECT key
FROM   jsonb_each('{"aaa": true, "bbb": false}')
WHERE  value = jsonb 'true'
```

(with `jsonb_each_text()` you rely on some JSON values' text representation).

You can even include some additional values, if you want:

```
WHERE  value IN (to_jsonb(TRUE), jsonb '"true"', to_jsonb('truthy'))
```

`IN` uses the equality operator under the hood.