# Get all keys of jsonb object in postgresql table where value is true

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, unnest, lateral-join

I have a postgresql table `customers` with `name` and `features` columns.

`features` contains jsonb objects like `{"featureA": true, "featureB": false, "featureC":true}`

What I'd like to get is an array of those keys in `features` where the value is true for each `name`, like:

```
name      | features
----------|---------------------
customerA | [featureA, featureC]
customerB | [featureB, featureC]
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920810/extracting-key-names-with-true-values-from-jsonb-object), I learnt that

```
SELECT key
FROM jsonb_each()
WHERE value = jsonb 'true'
```

is how you get keys that are true, but how do I do that for my table `customers`?

Something like

```
SELECT array_agg(key)
FROM   jsonb_each((select features from customers))
WHERE  value = jsonb 'true'
```

returns `SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing a lateral join:

```
select c.name, x.keys
from customers c
cross join lateral (
    select array_agg(x.key) keys
    from jsonb_each(c.features) x
    where x.value = jsonb 'true'
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use `jsonb_each()` in the select clause like this:

```
select
    x.name,
    json_agg(x.feature_name) as features
from (
    select
        c.name,
        row_to_json(jsonb_each(c.features))->>'key' as feature_name,
        (row_to_json(jsonb_each(c.features))->>'value')::bool as value
    from customers c
) as x
where x.value
group by x.name;
```